# Reading resource file in VSTO Shared Addin

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a Resource file in VSTO Shared add-in using the below code

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Exceptions", assembly);
return rm.GetString(key);
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Exceptions", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
String str = rm.GetString(key, ci);
return str;
```

but it is throwing an error saying check whether the resource file is embedded with the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a line like this at the start of your code and set a breakpoint upon it.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

You can then check the exact name of your resource within the assembly; which is the most likely cause of your issue.

Comment: how can i check the resouce name??

Comment: add a watch for assembly and check it's properties when the breakpoint is hit :)

Comment: I got it should be             
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("<MyAddinName.Exceptions", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());